# Laravel Eloquent groupby and sum

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm really new to eloquent, and I'm trying `groupby` the `employee_id` and do a `sum` function on the `deductions` field.. but I'm really having a hard time trying to sum the deductions.

here's my code:

```
$payroll = Timelog::groupBy('employee_id')->with('employee')->get(['employee_id','deductions']);
```

what I did is to add sum function after the groupby but I'm having an error..

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$payroll = Timelog::select('employee_id',DB::raw('SUM(deductions) as total_deductions'))->with('employee')->groupBy('employee_id')->get();
```

Comment: @SamTengWong: Glad to help :) and if my answer work for you then please accept my answer